# clearRect not working?

Tags: html, canvas

I am a very beginner web designer and I have two questions about this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#canvas1{border: #666 3px solid;}
</style>
<script type="application/javascript" language="javascript">
function draw (x,y){
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.save();
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.fillstyle = "rgb (0,200, 0)";
ctx.fillRect(x, 20, 50, 50);
ctx.restore();
x += 5;
var loop = setTimeout('draw('+x+', '+y+')', 100); 
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="draw(0,0)">Start</button>
<canvas id="canvas1" width="400" height="400"</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Why does the block always turn out black? and Why if I try to press start again, the clearRect function doesn’t work?

Comment: **Never** pass a string to `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`. Doing so is as bad as using `eval()` and it results in unreadable and possibly insecure code as soon as you use variables since you need to insert them into the string instead of passing the actual variable. The proper solution is `setInterval(function() { /* your code *) }, msecs);`. The same applies to `setTimeout()`. If you just want to call a single function without any arguments, you can also pass the function name directly: `setInterval(someFunction, msecs);` (note that there are **no** `()` behind the function name)

Comment: It calls a function, the function draw.

Comment: You did not get my point. Instead of passing an ugly string with the variables embedded using string concatenation you should pass an actual function: `setTimeout(function() { draw(x, y); }, 100);` or if you just need to support modern browsers: `setTimeout(draw.bind(this, x, y), 100);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click start you are starting a new loop that runs parallel to the one already started and depending on which one executes first your canvas would be cleared and filled twice (or as many times you started the loop - the more the more pronounced the flicker will be).

You need a mechanism to prevent the loop from starting several times. One way is to use a flag. I would also suggest you refactor the code a bit separating the loop and the drawing:

**[Live demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/nr5v2/)**

```
/// put these outside, no need to re-allocate them each time
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var w = canvas.width;
var h = canvas.height;
var x = 0;
var isRunning = false;

/// all loop-related here:
function loop() {

    /// call draw from inside the loop instead
    draw(x, 0); /// you are never using y so I just set 0 here...

    x += 5;

    if (isRunning && x <= w) {
        requestAnimationFrame(loop);  /// this is a better alternative
        //setTimeout(loop, 100);      /// optionally, but not recommended
    } else {
        isRunning = false;  /// box is outside visible area so we'll stop..
    }
}

/// keep draw() "clean", no loop code in here:
function draw(x, y) {
    /// no need for save/restore here...
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 200, 0)";
    ctx.fillRect(x, 20, 50, 50);
}
```

Your `fillStyle` was typed wrong, your `rgb(...` must be without space (as mentioned in the other answer - but it would only result in the fill style being black in this case), in addition you're missing a closing bracket for your `canvas` tag in the html.

To check for button clicks this is a more recommended way instead of inlining the JS in the html:

```
/// check for button clicks (start):
document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', function() {

    if (!isRunning) {     /// are we running? if not start loop
        isRunning = true; /// set flag so we can prevent multiple clicks
        x = 0;            /// reset x
        loop();           /// now we start the *loop*
    }

}, false);
```

And in your html:

```
<button id="start">Start</button>
```

Now you can easily make a pause button:

```
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
```

and add this to the script:

```
document.getElementById('stop').addEventListener('click', function() {

    isRunning = false;

}, false);
```

Comment: Thank you! Your way was very helpful, but I had to search up some things because i’m a very new to html(code in general).

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to use:

```
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0,200,0)";
```

with a capital 'S' and no space between 'rgb' and the opening bracket: http://jsfiddle.net/dtHjf/

Then, in terms of why pressing 'Start' multiple times causes the square to flicker, that's because each time you press it you're starting another animation loop, but without cancelling the old one, so that you've got multiple loops fighting with each other. If you make sure to cancel any pre-existing loop before you start a new one, you should be fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/dtHjf/2/

**HTML**:

```
<button id="startAnim">Start</button><br />
<canvas id="canvas1" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

**JS**:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    loop;

function draw(x, y) {

    ctx.save();
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0,200,0)";
    ctx.fillRect(x, 20, 50, 50);
    ctx.restore();

    x += 5;
    loop = setTimeout(function(){draw(x,y)}, 100);
}

document.getElementById('startAnim').onclick = function(){
    clearTimeout(loop);
    draw(0,0);
};
```

Also, this is unrelated to your problem, but you might want to take a look at `requestAnimationFrame`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame
http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Comment: Can you tell me why if I press start again, the square(rect) flashes? I think it is because the clearRect doesn’t work, but can you tell me how to fix it?

Comment: @matt729 yeah, i've added that to my answer

Comment: Thank you! This was also very helpful, and much more concise and easy to understand!